# Error in Passing data between Fragments in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

The code in my first Fragment(Home) is:

```
val frag:Fragment = Switches()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("text1",
                "Text Showing")
        frag.arguments = bundle
```

The code in 2nd Fragment(Switches) is:

```
val str:String = arguments!!.getString("test1")
```

I created both codes in OnCreatedView of Fragments.
Whenever I load the second fragment my app restated again. Is there any way to overcome this problem...?

Comment: *`app restated again.`* Means your app getting crashed you need to share that Crash report with question

Answer (score 1):

You've got..

`putString("text1")`

and

`.getString("test1")`

Seems they're not named correctly...
`

Comment: No bro! Still same

Comment: I've never seen double !! before in programming, but I've not worked Android.  Is it possible those exclamation marks aren't necessary?

Comment: @DanRayson Since it's Kotlin it's necessary to check the null pointer exception. That's the syntax of it I guess.

Comment: @ClintPaul do u know any other way to pass data between fragments? in kotlin Android

Answer (score 1):

```
val str:String = arguments!!.getString("test1")
```

You passed the key as "text1" from the first fragment. Make both the same and try again.

Comment: No bro! Still same

Comment: If I run this command on the receiving end:                                           
       val bundle:Bundle = arguments!!                                                         then still get the error

Comment: Try it like this, 
val value = arguments!!.getString("YourKey")

Comment: Brother thanks for help..... the above method is working only when I move between fragments using the button. It wasn't working because I was trying to get the data in Bottom Navigation. Thanks for your help